# How to delete an item in a json file via http delete request in nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, angular

So Basically, i have a JSON file which consists of user and group data. I want to delete a particular group. This is what my JSON file looks like: 
authdata.json:

```
[{
    "name": "Allan",
    "role": ["Group Admin", "Super Admin"],
    "group": ["Cool-Group", "ss"]
}, {
    "name": "super",
    "group": ["Nerd Group"],
    "role": ["Super Admin"]
}, {
    "name": "Terry",
    "role": ["Group Admin"],
    "group": ["Cool-Group"]
}, {
    "name": "Kaitlyn",
    "role": ["Group Admin"],
    "group": ["Nerd-Group"]
}, {
    "name": "Alex",
    "role": ["Group Admin"],
    "group": ["Cool-Group"]
}]
```

I'm just confused on how to handle a http delete request in nodeJS?
this how my angular component is sending the request to the server:
remove.component.ts:

```
RemoveGroup() {
    this.httpService.delete < any > (this.apiURL + 'deletegroup', {
        group: this.groups
    }).subscribe(
        data => {
            if (data['success'] == true) {
                alert(data.group + " is removed");
            } else {
                alert("No groups found");
            }
        },
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    );
}
```

This is the server side on NodeJS (reading the json file, assigning the data to a variable, trying to delete the group (which is not working for me) and writting back to the JSON file):
deletegroup.js:

```
app.delete('/api/deletegroup', (req, res) => {

    // localhost:3000/api/auth?username=Terry
    var groups = req.body.group;
    var userObj;

    fs.readFile('authdata.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            //Some error happended opening the file. No Success
            res.send({
                'group': '',
                'success': false
            });
        } else {
            userObj = JSON.parse(data);
            for (let i = 0; i < userObj.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; i < userObj.length; j++) {
                    if (userObj[i].group[j] == groups) {

                        userObj.splice(userObj.indexOf(groups), 1);
                        //find first instance of user name and success
                    }
                }
            }
            var newdata = JSON.stringify(userObj);

            fs.writeFile('authdata.json', newdata, 'utf-8', function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //Send response that registration was successfull.
                res.send({
                    'group': groups,
                    'success': true
                });
            });
            //no username was found that matched

        }
    });


});
```

Comment: In your loops, you have `if (userObj[i].group[j] == groups)`. Where is `groups` being set, and what is it being set to?

Comment: groups is basically the input that is being passed in a html file (user inputs the group name) and the ngModel is set to groups which grabs the value of the input field in html and assigns it to the variable groups. Now if you have a look at the RemoveGroup() function above, groups is being passed there in the httpService.delete request parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the problem is not with HTTP DELETE request. The concern is with how to remove a child node. See the below code snippet. You can pass the groups as an array to the deleteGroup function and see the result.

```
var data = [{
    "name": "Allan",
    "role": ["Group Admin", "Super Admin"],
    "group": ["Cool-Group", "ss"]
}, {
    "name": "Terry",
    "role": ["Group Admin"],
    "group": ["Cool-Group"]
}];

function deleteGroup(groupArray) {
  groupArray.map((needle)=>{
    data.map((userObj) => {
      if(userObj.group) {
        userObj.group.map((groupName, index)=>{
          if (groupName == needle){
            userObj.group.splice(index)
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No group present for this user.")
      }
    });
  });
  return data
}
//uncomment below line & run in console to see the results
//console.log(deleteGroup(["Cool-Group"]))
```

Try out directly in Jsbin - https://jsbin.com/pejidag/1/edit?js,console

Happy coding!